# Turn an Excel spreadsheet into an array

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

How do I turn a Pandas dataset into an array?

I currently have an Excel spreadsheet with data and

```
data = pandas.read_excel('breathing_data.xls')
```

appears to work fine, however, now I want to `numpy.diff` and it appears to only work on arrays, anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html):

```
data = pandas.read_excel('breathing_data.xls').values
```

Or 
[`as_matrix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.as_matrix.html):

```
data = pandas.read_excel('breathing_data.xls').as_matrix()
```

EDIT:

You need [`tolist()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.tolist.html), if `DataFrame` has only one column:

```
data = pandas.read_excel('breathing_data.xls').tolist()
```

Comment: Still not working with numpy.diff()
When i go numpy.diff([11,2,3,4]) it works
But numpy.diff(data) doesnt work

Comment: when i use the data it returns an empty array

Comment: Ok, what return `data = pandas.read_excel('breathing_data.xls')` ?

Comment: But why do you dont use [`diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html) ?